# Cucumber tests execute fine on local machine, but fail while running in jenkins

Tags: eclipse, maven, testing, jenkins, cucumber

I'm new to maven and eclipse. Working on a project ran into an issue while trying to integrate with jenkins.
Executing "clean test" or "clean install" goal, runs tests fine in the Eclipse on local machine, but using same goal in Jenkins fails the tests with:

Failure in before hook:StepDefinitionsMyProject.before(Scenario)

Message: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class com.myCompany.stepDefinitions.StepDefinitionsProject.

My files are located in src/main/java
The cukeRunnerTest is in src/test/java
Feature files are in src/test/resources

POM snippet..

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any thoughts on as to why this might be happenning?

Comment: Please share the stacktrace from Jenkins. There is probably something missing. With some luck, it will be possible to see in the stacktrace. Are you able to run on your machine from a command line prompt, thus reducing Eclipse from the equation?

Comment: @ThomasSundberg Thanks for taking time to look at this for me. I figured out the problem. I'm not sure if this is a standard practice for Maven projects, but our project had two different pom files. One was responsible for building the project and packaging it. While the second pom file was responsible for unpackaging the jar and running tests. On the local machine while executing the tests, all the resources are available.. but when you get jenkins into play, that is no longer the case. Again, thanks for taking time to look at this.

Comment: In a multi module Maven project you will have a pom for each module and a parent pom that ties everything together. Having just two poms sounds unusual. I would expect 1, 3, 4, 5, 6... pom files as there will always be a parent and one for each module.

Comment: I'm assuming by "parent pom" you're referring to "Effective POM", in that case yes we have 3 different pom files in the project. I just Assumed that "Effective POM" is a given for a maven project, that's why I didn't even think about mentioning anything about it, sorry.